# unique count of strings in a column in excel or office 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to get the unique count  of a text in a column in excel. In office 365, I have used `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(B2:B1169))`  but it is not returning the count of text as expected. I want to get the count of text and if it is repeated, it shouldn't duplicate the count. For example, GCP cloud storage error is repeated 4 times and for the second occurrence, the count shouldn't be 5. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample Data for each row:

```
GCP cloud storage error
GCP IAM Service account disabled
projects/gcp-dmz/account/apache@gcp.com/values/434234234242
GCP VPN network auth issue
GCP cloud storage error
GCP cloud storage error
GCP cloud storage error
```

Output:

```
Text                                                               Count
GCP cloud storage error                                              4
GCP IAM Service account disabled                                     2    
projects/gcp-dmz/account/apache@gcp.com/values/434234234242          0
GCP VPN network auth issue                                           0
GCP cloud storage error                                              0 ( count shouldn't be 5 )
GCP cloud storage error                                              0
GCP cloud storage error                                              0
GCP IAM Service account disabled                                     0
```

Thank you

Comment: Unique returns the unique list not a unique list and a count.  CountA will will give you the count of unique items not the count of how many of each item.  A simple COuNTIF() would do this: `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$1169,$B$2:$B$1169)`  This will spill the results, just put that in C2.

Comment: Don't tag Excel 2007 or 2010 if you have Office 365. Office 365 has so much more functionality.